# Get the names of list variables when provided as function parameters

Tags: r

Lets say I have a function that accepts variables that are always part of a list.

```
myfun <- function(x$name,y$name) { 
 # stuff 
}
```

What I'd like to do is get the names used.

```
alist <- list(Hello=1,Goodbye=2)

myfun(alist$Hello, alist$Goodbye) { 
 # I want to be able to work with the characters "Hello" and "Goodby" in here
}
```

So, within my function, how would I get the characters "Hello" and "Goodbye". Given `alist$Hello` and `alist$Goodbye`

Comment: In that case, why not pass `alist` function argument like: `myfun <- function(x)` argument and access the names using `names(x)`?

Comment: Downvoters should have the courtesy to comment as to why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recall that `plot.default` does this with `deparse(substitute(`:

```
a <- list(a="hello",b=c(1,2,3))
f <- function(x,y) { print(deparse(substitute(x))); print(deparse(substitute(y))) }
f(a$a,a$b)
#[1] "a$a"
#[1] "a$b"
```

Comment: This led me to `?quote` which seems like it doesn't cat() anything else to the screen. Hence +1 and checkmark. `as.character(quote(x))[3]` gives me what I wanted.

Comment: One problem is that, the list need not have the elements that you're accessing at all... with this method. `f(a$x, a$y)` gives `a$x, a$y` and I'm not sure if it's desirable.

Comment: @Arun You could raise an error or warning if `is.null` on the arguments came up `TRUE`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
myfun <- function(x) { print(substitute(x))}
myfun(iris$Sepal.Length)
## iris$Sepal.Length
```

Comment: Given that you answered at the same time +1. Checkmark goes to lower score - he needs it more!

Answer (score 3):

I'd create the function with a list argument:

```
myfun <- function(l) {
    print(names(alist))
}
myfun(alist)
# [1] "Hello"   "Goodbye"
```